# Sorting ObservableCollection Using Custom Logic

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, observablecollection

New to `WPF` and also the `ObservableCollection` I need to sort it in my own way, and keep it sorted everytime something adds or removes from it.

```
ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
```

The user object is like so :

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOp { get; set; }
    public bool IsAway { get; set; }
}
```

I would like all the `IsOp's` at the top of the list, in alphabetical order. Then all the non-ops in alphabetical order following them.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Continuous LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `CollectionView`:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(users);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IsOp", ListSortDirection.Descending));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

When you will bind the view to that list, the items will appear in the specified order.

Using the trick shown [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/11/30/wpf-using-linq-to-shape-data-in-a-collectionview/), you can even use Linq:

```
var query =
    from u in users.ShapeView()
    orderby u.IsOp descending, u.Name ascending
    select u;

query.Apply();
```

Comment: But now my listbox in WPF wont update automatically because its not an observablecollection?

Comment: Yes it will, if you bind the ItemsSource of the ListBox to the ObservableCollection (you don't have to bind to `query`; this is just a trick to specify the sort order using Linq)

Comment: Thomas, so if Im understanding right your saying that I do the stuff above once, and it will permenantly change the inner workings of my observable collection, so no need to change any bindings, everything will be sorted whenever it changes?

Comment: @Muhammad, yes, once you have set the sortdescription of collectionviewsource, all the further changes to underlying collection will be automatically reflected to sorted data on view

Comment: @MuhammadA, actually it won't change "the inner workings of your observable collection", but it will change the properties of the default view of your collection, which is used for binding